# NA value in RAPIDMINER?

Tags: rapidminer

what is equivalent's of R ('NA'|'NULL'|'None') value in RAPIDMINER? Or what is some other value for denoting that this value should not be taken into consideration while making calculations, or that it is missing?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general tech support.

Comment: I do not ask how to use a washing machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing values show up as '?' in the data view of example sets and they are counted in the meta-data view. Imported data can obviously have them and you can generate your own using the Declare Missing Values operator or within the Generate Attributes operator using a code fragment containing an invalid mathematical operation like 0/0. You can test for the presence of a missing value by using the missing() function within the Generate Attributes operator.

Comment: A more direct way to add missing values in an expression in Generate Attributes is to directly use the available basic constants `MISSING_NOMINAL`, `MISSING_DATE_TIME`, `MISSING_NUMERIC`, ... shown on the right hand side in the "Inputs" panel.

Answer (score 0):

It is probabbly the question mark: `?`

Comment: For clarification: The "missing values" are represented visually by a `?` in the example set view. They are not represented internally as the character `?`, so when testing for missing values, an operation like `=="?"` would fail. There are special operators or expressions available to deal with them.